# Why am I unable to click this selectable option in my settings?

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation, white-framework

http://puu.sh/mVDoM/069787ca8d.png

I am using teststack white and I tried using:

```
ListViewRow presetter = p7window.Get<ListViewRow>(SearchCriteria.ByText("Presetter"));
presetter.Click();

TableRow presetter = p7window.Get<TableRow>(SearchCriteria.ByText("Presetter"));
presetter.Click();

ListItem presetter = p7window.Get<ListItem>(SearchCriteria.ByText("Presetter"));
presetter.Click();
```

I also tried using "Name row 1" and "row 1" for the string that is in the argument.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify and call it to find by text, it is saying the "text" property, not that it might contain text with that value. TableRow doesn't usually have text property, but rather uses things like "Value" "RowIndex" etc.

Also, you should be aware of the place of the element in the tree, you might have to pass it to a parent control.

i.e.

```
List list = p7window.Get<List>(SearchCriteria.ByValue("Presetter"));
ListItem li = list.Get<ListItem>(SearchCriteria.ByValue("Presetter"));
```

Comment: If read the last part of my text, it states that I have tried using "Name row 1" instead of "Presetter"

I have tried 
     TableRow presetter = p7window.Get<TableRow>(SearchCriteria.ByText("Name Row 1"));
presetter.Click();

http://puu.sh/mVFNA/7fec43dc94.png

Comment: You don't have a method SearchCriteria.ByValue? Text is a property that is not showing up when you are looking at it in the tree.

Comment: I would see what properties you can match against with NativeProperty, otherwise just by those few things you aren't going to be able to many advanced things.

Comment: SearchCriteria.ByNativeProperty(Value, "Presetter");

Comment: Error: Value does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

Try to get **AutomationElement** for it.

```
***.GetElement(SearchCriteria.ByText("Presetter"));
```

If it's not null find a point by **getClicablePoint()** and perform click by mouse like **Mouse.Instance.Click()**

If the element is not reachable by any SearachCriteria - try to use native MS UI Automation:

1. Get the closest root control to yours.
2. Take Autoelement property from it.
3. Find whole children list of it like **AutomationElement.FindAll(Treescrope.Descendals, PropertyCondition.TrueCondion)** _
4. Find your element in Autoelements Array by any property you need.
5. Get **invoke pattern** from it and use Invoke()